# Network shared folders dont show on other devices until I change the state of IPv6

Tags: windows, networking, file-sharing, sharing

My PC is connected to the router via cable, it has some folders shared on the network which I don't see on any other devices connected via WiFi, until I change the state of IPv6 in network adapter settings as shown here
[Adapter Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDdNU.png)

Adapter Settings
Meaning the network folders don't show on other devices and if this "Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6)" is checked, when i uncheck, they suddenly appear on other devices. and if this is unchecked when network folders are not showing, i check this and then they suddenly show up.
can anyone help me figure this out please? Thank you!